# SSIS Table Locking on Transactions

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016, ssis-2012

I am trying to upload data into MSSQL 2016 using SSIS.

The process is:

[image: SSIS Process]

What I am trying to do is rollback all data if anything fails. First I tried using `TransactionOption=Required` but this locked the target tables until the SSIS sequence had completed. I  have then tried using SQL Tasks to create BEGIN, ROLLBACK and COMMIT transactions as I read this is preferred by some and it does not lock the tables. However, my tables are still locked. I am unable to SELECT data from the tables involved until the sequence has completed.

```
Transactions:
BEGIN TRANSACTION T1;
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION T1;
COMMIT TRANSACTION T1
```

Is what I am trying to do even possible and if so what is the best way to do it?

Comment: It sounds like you might be experiencing 'Lock Escalation' if you are altering/inserting over 5000 rows then SQL will lock the entire table.

Comment: I've never seen hand crafted transaction logic before. Use the SSIS built in stuff. What I HAVE seen often is using SSIS to bulk load data into a holding table first, and then call a Stored Procedure to process the new data into the target location(s).

Comment: In the dataflow tasks, do the destination components have the tablock option checked?  This is the default for OLEDB destinations.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz No, the only option that is checked is "Check Constraint"

Comment: @TDP the issue is that I am deleting data and inserting data via more than task and therefore would want to rollback all 3 tasks if any tasks inside the sequence container fails

Comment: @pacreely, table 1 only has 147 rows and table 2 has 200 rows so very small datasets

Comment: This definitely seems like a lock escalation issue as @pacreely stated.  How many rows are typically being inserted?  If there are so few rows, it would seem like the whole transaction should complete very quickly

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz, it is under 200 rows. The only reason I have noticed it is because I was debugging SSIS and therefore the transactions were paused. I was just trying to understand the process better, which I think I do now. I have attached an image below of the DTC setup is this OK? As Network DTC Access was not originally enabled or is this going to cause me problems?

Comment: What you have setup for DTC will work.  However, it would be simpler to use the built-in functionality in SSIS.  If the table is always going to be this small, then you can always expected it to be locked during loading.  It should be pretty brief with so few rows.  If this is not acceptable for reporting, you might look at enabling snapshot isolation on the the database, which will allow the reports to view a previous version of table.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz, I thought built-in functionality of SSIS uses DTC for transactions? I have now removed the SQL Tasks for transactions BEGIN, ROLLBACK and COMMIT and set the Sequence container "SEQ Import Data" to have a value of TransactionOption=Required. For this to work I needed to configure DTC on the local machine (dev machine) and remote MSSQL server. Did I get this right? Thanks

Comment: That sounds right.  You'll need to test it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting TransactionOption=Required is the same as issuing a TSQL BEGIN TRAN except that you are responsible for implementing your own commit/roll back logic. SSIS may use the Distributed Transaction Coordinator, DTC, or issue begin tran statements directly to your SQL Server instance.

As the comments indicate, SQL Server will attempt to lock the whole table if it's pouring in great quantities (5k) of rows. This is desirable because SSIS is a high performance ETL tool and I don't want to play nicely with other processes - I have a ton of data to load and everyone else get outta the way.

> I am unable to SELECT data from the tables involved until the sequence has completed.

You're likely using the [default isolation level](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-t-sql-transaction-isolation-levels-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/) in your client - for SSMS it is read committed. Maybe your app can handle "dirty reads" and all that that implies.

If you cannot handle dirty reads, stage your data to a different table (using your data flow task) and when that is complete, use an Execute SQL Task to issue an insert statement. I usually have an explicit `tablock` hint at this point because I know I'm loading lots of data and I try to help the engine. The benefit of the staging table approach is that it eliminates network traffic as a factor in holding the table lock longer than is optimal.

Comment: The tables have only 200 or less rows currently. I have set the TransactionOption to NotSupported as I was hoping to build my own transaction logic so it work similar to if I did it in SSMS.

If I write is SSMS:

begin transaction T1;
delete from Table1
delete from Table2

I am able to run the below queries before I either commit T1 or Roll it back. Why is this different when I run the delete SQL task is SSIS?

select * from Table1
select * from Table2

Comment: There is always a transaction involved when you are inserting data - either explicit or implicit. In your scenario here, do you run the select statements within the same explicit transaction?

Comment: Apologies, I have just noticed the link you attached, which I have read and this now makes more sense thank you. And yes when running the SELECT I did it in the the same session as the DELETE, which is why it ran. After reading your article I tried the SELECT again inside a different session which boded the same result as SSIS. So I now understand SSIS is doing what it should do. So my next question is... Should I use DTC or my own method for transactions, DTC I suspect? I have done away with staging tables as the data is minimal (no more than 200 rows inserted)

Answer (score 0):

The TransactionOption property exists at the package level, container level (e.g. For Loop, Foreach Loop, Sequence, etc.), as well as just about any Control Flow task (e.g. Execute SQL task, Data Flow task, etc.).
TransactionOption can be set to one of the following:

- **Required** - if a transaction exists join it else start a new one
- **Supported** - if a transaction exists join it (this is the default)
- **NotSupported** - do not join an existing transaction

I think you should use `TransactionOption=Supported` for the solution of this particular issue.

---

Comment: I understand this, I originally set the TransactionOption to Required on the sequence container but the problem is by enabling this it locks the involved tables until the sequence has either commited or rolled back. Meaning that reporting on the table would be suspended until the sequence has completed. Is there not anyway you can do this without locking the tables?

Answer (score 0):

When using DTC from my DEV PC I have read I need to enable Network DTC Access on the remote SQL server. Have I done this correctly? Will enabling this cause any problems to MSSSQL?

[DTC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V7Ja.png)